# SetWindowsHookEx Hook into Explorer To Intercept Win32API call

Tags: winapi, hook, setwindowshookex

If I want to intercept a win32 API call, specifically one of the win32 api calls listed at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-functions

I presume I need to:

1. Get the explorer thread id, either from some win32 api call to get threadId by process name (or some special one that exists for explorer).
2. Call SetWindowsHookExA()

`SetWindowsHookExA(WH_CALLWNDPROC, HookProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), explorerThreadId)`

After I call SetWindowsHookExA, I presume I then analyze the messages that are sent to my custom written HookProc to see which win32 api call i'm intercepting, to then react based on that? Are there any good examples out there for identifying which win32 api call the hookProc is being called for? Or examples where somebody has hooked one particular win32api call successfully?

Comment: The [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) page links to [Using Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-hooks) sample code. Note however that what you hook is events and messages, not APIs. For that, check out [detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) or similar libraries.

Comment: You need to DLL-inject yourself into the target process, and then *detour* the functions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that information. Are there examples of how to hook into APIs without using detours?

Comment: @user8694-03 You *can't* hook into API functions across process boundaries.  You MUST inject your code into the target process first, and THEN hook the functions from inside that process. `SetWindowsHookEx()` is one way to inject code, such as via a `WH_GETMESSAGE`/`WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook, which runs in the context of a hooked thread. Or there is `CreateRemoteThread()`. Many ways to inject code, do a search online.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. so I need a function in a dll that I inject into explorer.exe, got it. Ok also sounds like once my function in a DLL is injected, the i use SetWindowsHookEx again to hook into specific win32api calls?

Comment: @user8694-03 No, `SetWindowsHookEx()` has NOTHING to do with hooking into other functions. Get that out of your head.  You MUST detour the functions that you want to intercept

Comment: ok got it thanks. ok and is detour a generic term or would it require the use of the detour library?

Comment: @user8694-03 it is a general term, though Microsoft provides an actual implementation in a [detours library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/), and [technical information about what it actually does under the hood](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/wiki), particularly the part about [Interception of Binary Functions](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/wiki/OverviewInterception). You might also want to research tools like [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor), [WinAPIOverride](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/), etc and see how they work

Comment: ok thanks you're super helpful. If you know of some good examples for detouring functions that would be great. Otherwise I will search the internet for tutorials.